# The output from my selenium script is blank, how do I fix?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

First time using selenium for web scraping a website, and I'm fairly new to python. I have tried to scrape a Swedish housing site to extract price, address, area, size, etc., for every listing for a specific URL that shows all houses for sale in a specific area called "Lidingö".

I managed to bypass the pop-up window for accepting cookies.

However, the output I get from the terminal is blank when the script runs. I get nothing, not an error, not any output.

What could possibly be wrong?

The code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

s = Service("/Users/brustabl1/hemnet/chromedriver")
url = "https://www.hemnet.se/bostader?location_ids%5B%5D=17846&item_types%5B%5D=villa"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)


# The cookie button clicker

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[62]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button"))).click()


lists = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a/div[2]')

for list in lists:
    adress = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[2]/a/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h2')

    area = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[2]')

    price = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]')

    rooms = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*
[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]')

    size = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')

print(adress.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of flaws in your code...

```
lists = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a/div[2]')
```

in your code this returns a list of elements in the variable *lists*

```
for list in lists:
    adress = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[2]/a/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h2')

    area = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[2]')

    price = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]')

    rooms = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*
[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]')

    size = list.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="result"]/ul[1]/li[1]/a/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')

print(adress.text)
```

you are not storing the value of each address in a list, instead, you are updating its value through each iteration.And xpath refers to the exact element, your loop is selecting the same element over and over again!

And scraping text through selenium is a bad practice, use BeautifulSoup instead.